# How do you add digits to the front of a number?

Tags: java

How would you add digits to the beginning of a number (left hand side) without using a string?

I know that if you try this:

(Some psuedo code)

Let's say I try to make number 534

```
int current = 5;
int num = 0;

num = (num*10) +current;
```

then

```
int current = 3;
int num = 5

num = (num*10) + current;
```

**would make: 53**

then

```
int current = 4;
int num = 53;

num = (num*10) + current;
```

**would make 534**

It would keep adding numbers to the right hand side of the number.

However, I am a bit confused on how you would do the opposite. How would you add numbers on the left, so instead of 534 it makes 435?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 3):

```
int num = 123;
int digits = 456;

int powerOfTen = (int) Math.pow(10, (int) (Math.log10(digits) + 1));

int finalNum = digits * powerOfTen + num;

System.out.println(finalNum);  // Output: 456123
```

The number of digits in digits is calculated using `Math.log10` and `Math.pow`, and then used to determine the appropriate power of 10 to multiply digits by. The result is then added to `num` to obtain the final number with the added digits.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the digit to add by increasing powers of 10 before summing with the current number.

```java
int num = 0, pow = 1;
num += 5 * pow;
pow *= 10;
num += 3 * pow;
pow *= 10;
num += 4 * pow; // num = 435 at this point
pow *= 10;
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An example without the use of libraries could be this:

First, get the number of digits. Then calculate the number you have to add to your initial number. The sum of these two numbers is the result you're after.

```
private int addNumberInFrontOf(int initialNumber, int initialNumberToAdd){
    int numberOfDigits = getDigits(initialNumber);

    int getActualNumberToAdd = getNumberToAdd(initialNumberToAdd, numberOfDigits);

    return initialNumber + getActualNumberToAdd;
}
```

To calculate the number of digits, you can count the number of times you can divide the initial number by 10. Notice you need to use a `do-while` loop because otherwise the loop wouldn't be triggered if your initial number was 0.

```
private int getDigits(int number) {
    int count = 0;

    do {
        number = number / 10;
        count += 1;
    } while (number != 0);

    return count;
}
```

Calculate the number you need to add to your initial number by multiplying the initial number to add with the magnitude. The magnitude simply is 1 multiplied with 10 for every digit in the initial number.

```
private int getNumberToAdd(int number, int numberOfDigits) {
    int magnitude = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
        magnitude *= 10;
    }
    return number * magnitude;
}
```

For example, `addNumberInFrontOf(456, 123)` would result in `123456`. Of course, this method won't work when you use positive and negative numbers combined.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String` for example.

```java
public static int addLeft(int cur, int num) {
    return num == 0 ? cur : Integer.parseInt(cur + String.valueOf(num));
}
```

In case you want to avoid working with `String`, you can use recursion instead.

```java
public static int addLeft(int cur, int num) {
    return num == 0 ? cur : addLeft(cur, num / 10) * 10 + num % 10;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use some math, in python

```py
import math
def addLeft(digit, num):
    return digit * 10 ** int(math.log10(num) + 1) + num
```

Note that this might fail for very large numbers on account of precision issues

```bash
>>> addLeft(2, 100)
2100
>>> addLeft(3, 99)
399
>>> addLeft(6, 99999999999999)
699999999999999
>>> addLeft(5, 999999999999999)
50999999999999999  (oops)
```

Comment: I should mention that because of how doubles work, this method will work for any output number that fits into a 32-bit (in fact, 52-bit) integer. So if you're in a language like c and using ints it's actually very valid